# Purpose of the character "\" in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I notice "\" being added to the end of some of the lines in a shell script. I am new to working with shell scripts and googling did not give me anything from which I could understand what it does. Please let me know what this does.

Comment: Search for the phrase "line continuation"

Comment: it's a line continuation character. you want a new line for readability but you don't want the code to be parsed that way